# How to Add a spray painting gradient to half of the webpage?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a background spray painting gradient only on top half of my website's homepage.
Something similar to background of [this website](http://taylorstitch.com/).
Can someone please help me to do this with cross browser support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a large background image using Css. You can shorthand it if you like.

```
body {
background:url(pathtoyourimage/image.gif) top left repeat-x scroll #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Background Image: http://www.tizag.com/pics/BannerTileBackground.gif

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://www.tizag.com/pics/BannerTileBackground.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x; 
    background-position: top;
}
```

Comment: You can also use the background shorthand and try to set your image to your html tag instead of the body, which I prefer in this case:
html 'or' body { background: url(yourImage.jpg) repeat-x 0 0; }